# button onClick action

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am developing a contacts list android app and I am trying to insert 5 new edit text fields every time I press the add address button. I tried to make the text fields in the java file inside the onClick method but it didn't work, the thing is that I heard that you can add a layout inside another layout and now I am trying to add a layout with the 5 text fields inside the layout containing the button. This is the code of the .xml file containing some other fields and the add address button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/add_contact_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/first_name_editText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/first_name_hint" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/second_name_editText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/second_name_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile_phone_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/cell_phone_hint"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/work_phone_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/work_phone_hint"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email_text_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_address_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_address_text" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/address_spinner"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the code of a new .xml file containing the five edit text fields:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typeOfAdresstextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/spinner_value"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address_street_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"

            android:hint="@string/street_hint"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address_number_editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"

            android:hint="@string/address_number_hint"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address_city_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"

            android:hint="@string/city_hint"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address_state_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"

            android:hint="@string/state_hint"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address_zipcode_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"

            android:hint="@string/zipcode_hint"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </TableRow>


</LinearLayout>
```

My goal is to insert these 5 text fields below the button and the spinner, and every time I press the button these text fields appear again for the user to be able to add all the addresses that he/she wants (below the previous filled  address text fields). I don't know if this is the right way but if there is another way to accomplish this I am open to suggestions. Here I leave a [sketch](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36217960/add%20contact%20user%20interface.png) of what I want to accomplish

Comment: Ok, what have you done with your code, are you getting any error. If so, what is the error?

Comment: I tried to make the text fields in java with this piece of code adapted to what I want, first I created a linear layout final LinearLayout subParentView = new LinearLayout(this); then I added the text fields with EditText edittext = new EditText(getApplicationContext()); then I add it to the subparent subParentView.addView(edittext); but when I run this the activity is all blank, the first text fields and the button does not appear

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a `FrameLayout` after your `TableLayout` in the first XML layout file then inflate the 2nd layout into the `FrameLayout`.  Or, just embed the 2nd layout into the first within a containing layout (like the `FrameLayout` I suggested above) and mark the container as `android:visibility="gone"`.  When your button is pressed, change the visibility and your other 5 fields will become visible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but I already tried the visibility property, the thing about this is that it just makes visible the set of textfields already creted on the second xml and I want to be able to create more sets of textfields as the ones in the second xml (like make blank copies of these text fields for the user to fill)

Comment: Then you can go with the first approach and inflate new child objects into the 2nd layout.  Or, probably a better approach, would be to use a `ListView` which you are inserting new rows into an adapter and the list grows as you add new entries.  You just need to implement the appropriate backing class and adapter.

Comment: I'm a newbie in all this android stuff, is there any chance that you know of any tutorial out there for me to learn how to inflate the layout?

Comment: Offhand, no, I don't know of one.  However, if you look at the `LayoutInflater` documentation as well as look at some of the samples from the SDK you should be able to find what you need.